# Read integers from binary file in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, file, byte

I have a binary file which represents an old punchcard. The file has following data:

```
Function(unsigned int8 min: 0, max: +255), 
Vertical Movement (signed int16 min: -32.768,  max: +32.767) 
Horizontal Movement (signed int16 min: -32.768,  max: +32.767)
```

This pattern will repeat with different values approx. 100.000 times and will represent a 2D CAD Design with machine functions.

Each line of the file/punchcard has 5 Bytes ( 1 x Uint8, 2 x int16). What is the best way to read it?
In C# I used a stream to read one byte after another but I cannot find examples to do it in Swift 5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can open a binary file using a function like this (Swift 5):

```
func getFile(forResource resource: String, withExtension fileExt: String?) -> [UInt8]? {
    // See if the file exists.    
    guard let fileUrl: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: resource, withExtension: fileExt) else {
        return nil
    }
    
    do {
        // Get the raw data from the file.
        let rawData: Data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)

        // Return the raw data as an array of bytes.
        return [UInt8](rawData)
    } catch {
        // Couldn't read the file.
        return nil
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if let bytes: [UInt8] = getFile(forResource: "foo", withExtension: "json") {
    for byte in bytes {
        // Process single byte...
    }
}
```

Then simply iterate over the bytes and format them to your specifications.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. It needs only a little change in the usage part. Where you write `fileExt: "json"` Xcode tells to change it to `withExtension: "json" `